# opencv_createsamples "Assertion Failed" Error, line 466

Tags: opencv, image-recognition, training-data, haar-classifier

I have a problem with `opencv_createsamples` operation. I use the command to prepare files:

```
opencv_createsamples.exe -info D:\Almanac\haar\generating\data\Good.dat 
-vec samples.vec -num 770 -w 80 -h 114
```

and receive [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ipy.png):

```
OpenCV(3.4.6) Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x 
 + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + 
 + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file
   c:\build\3_4_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp,
   line 466
```

My info file looks like this

```
Good\1.jpg 1 578 559 658 673
Good\2.jpg 1 578 697 658 811
```

I've tried to change some properties (added number of good samples, changed parameters -w -h from (-w 7 -h 10) to state above), but it didn't worked for me

I use openCV version 3.4.6.

I really hope for your help

Comment: Can you add the Assertion Error into your question?

Comment: i've added it , i'm sorry for formatting, it's my first question here

Comment: can you try subsets of your info file whether only some of the samples make problems? Are 3rd and 4th values w and h or pixel coordinates?

Comment: @Micka if i understood you  correctly, 578 559 658 673 - are coordinates, not a value of object height and width. All pictures are looked the same, it is a screenshot of my desctop and an object (which size is 80x114 pixels) changes its location

Comment: @Micka Thank you for your comment. i've reread a guide in English and undestood that i have to set height and width as 3th and 4th paramters instead of coordinates. Thank you again)